# Adding all Maven dependencies to Arquillian

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jboss-arquillian

How do you add all dependencies in the POM to arquillian?

```
Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeDependencies()
                .as(File.class);
```

I found that line, but I `Maven` is red in intellij because it doesn't find the class. I don't know which dependencies I need. Or are there better ways?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: All the dependencies that my code have (ToStringBuilder, EqualsBuilder...). I already said that I need all the dependencies in the POM.

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Comment: It doesn't. If your code has some dependencies, then it should get them from somewhere, right ? The two classes that you've mentioned come from `commons-lang`. I don't know what arquillian has to do here.

Comment: Please, just stop when you can't answer.

Answer (score 36):

### Adding Arquillian dependencies

Add Arquillian dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Add the ShrinkWrap resolver (Maven implementation) to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are using JUnit, add the Arquillian JUnit container to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

### Importing Maven dependencies

In your test class, within the method annotated with `@Deployment`, import the runtime dependencies with the following line:

```java
File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
        .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
```

And add the dependencies to your deploy using the method `addAsLibraries(files)`:

```java
WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                           .addClass(MyClass1.class)
                           .addClass(MyClass2.class)
                           .addClass(MyClass3.class)
                           .addAsLibraries(files);
```

### This is how your test class will look like if you are using JUnit

```java
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.File;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTestClassWithMavenDependencies {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {

        // Import Maven runtime dependencies
        File[] files = Maven.resolver()
                            .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
                            .importRuntimeDependencies()
                            .resolve()
                            .withTransitivity()
                            .asFile();

        // Create deploy file    
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                                   .addClass(MyClass1.class)
                                   .addClass(MyClass2.class)
                                   .addClass(MyClass3.class)
                                   .addAsLibraries(files);

        // Show the deploy structure
        System.out.println(war.toString(true)); 

        return war;
    }

    // Create your tests here
}
```

---

<sub>**Note 1:** The above solution has been tested with Arquillian `1.1.8.Final`. Check the most recent version of Arquillian artifacts on the [documentation](http://arquillian.org/modules/core-platform/#artifacts).</sub>

<sub>**Note 2:** For more details on how to resolve dependencies, have a look at the [ShrinkWrap Resolvers documentation](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver#resolving-dependencies).</sub>

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error as you. It's because of incorrect shrinkwrap versions. See correct versions in the second piece of code.

```
package alehro.testgf2;

import java.io.File;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import alehro.p1.C1;
import alehro.p1.C2;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class Test1 {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createTestArchive()  {
         File[] libs = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().asFile();


        WebArchive res = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war");
        for(File file : libs){
            res.addAsLibrary(file);
        }       
        res.addPackages(true, "alehro.p1");

        return res;          

    }
    @Test
    public void test1(){
            //third party lib
        DateTimeFormatter inputDF = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
        DateTime dt1 = inputDF.parseDateTime("28 Nov 2012 23:23:23 +04");           
        Assert.assertNotNull(dt1);  

            //all classes from alehro.p1
        Assert.assertEquals("Failure", "I'm C1", C1.getMyName()) ;
        Assert.assertEquals("Failure", "I'm C2", C2.getMyName()) ;

    }
}
```

I had a harsh time resolving maven dependencies. Below is working solution, but I'm sure it can be simplified more.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha-5</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Original idea is from here: [How to I add Maven artifacts to my ShrinkWrap archives?](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToIAddMavenArtifactsToMyShrinkWrapArchives)

Answer (score 6):

This dzone article [Using the ShrinkWrap Maven Resolver for Arquillian Tests](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-shrinkwrap-maven) which might be useful. It suggests:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
  <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Another way you can find a class when you don't know which artifact it's in is to use [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/). Here's a search for the class you are looking for:

- [fc:"org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven"](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven%22)

It shows the artifacts containing that class. However, the class is in an API jar, and you'll also want the implementation jar as mentioned above and in the aformentioned article.

Answer (score 0):

The org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.Maven class is included by shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven 2.0.0-beta-1 or later.